# Re-execute tail command via subprocess for newly created files

Tags: python, loops, subprocess, tail

I can't think of an algorithm to re-execute the tail command after a certain time. In other words, refresh. Right now, the code works perfectly for any existing files with *.log. However, when a new log is created, "tail" command does not see that new file unless I stop and re-execute the command again. So I'm trying to come up with an algorithm where I can have python re-execute the subprocess.Popen line after x amount of time... I tried a nested while loop but that just kept printing the last line of the log file continuously... I tried using "watch tail . . . . . " but it didn't like it and the output was blank...

Here is the code I have now:

```
syslog = []
tail = subprocess.Popen('tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log', shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = tail.stdout.readline()
    line = line.strip('\n')
    if(re.search('mnt',line)) or (line == ''):
        pass    
    else:
        syslog.append(line)
        multithread_engine(syslog)
        del syslog[:]
```

Comment: This is really not ideal -- you'll miss contents in the transition. It'd be less failure-prone if you had one `tail` instance per file -- then starting a new one doesn't mean shutting down/restarting others.

Comment: Also, I'm very surprised that `**` is working for you -- `shell=True` prepends `sh -c` to the command line run by `subprocess.Popen()`. A copy of `sh` that supports `**` is... pretty nearly unheard of; I wonder if it's just acting like a single `*` but you haven't caught the difference yet.

Comment: Maybe you might ask how to follow changes to all files in a tree in Python, instead of assuming an answer that involves actually using the `tail` command? There definitely already exist Python libraries for watching for creation of new files (deletion of files, etc), and there definitely already exist native-Python implementations of `tail`. I wouldn't be surprised if there already existed out-of-the-box code combining both.

Comment: (That said, if you're trying to reimplement logstash, why not... just use logstash? That'll do all the work of putting all your logs, across all your log files, together in a single stream, whether you want it on RabbitMQ, in a Redis queue, directly indexed into ElasticSearch, or in whatever other format).

Comment: you can watch the size of syslog, if it increments reboot the program